# Creating a PointOfSale System

Tags: pos

General question, I am trying to develop a Point of Sale System for use a a company I current work for that includes MANY locations (pizza industry). I am experienced in Java(web)/python/c#/mySQL and learning more languages more this project. My question is what would be the best language or combo of to develop a program like this? I dont want to create a web based application I want a create something that could be installed and ran directly at each store

also if anyone know where or how I might be able to find some "starter" files I wouldn't be mad

Comment: With your experience in Java(web)/python/c#/mySQL etc. I imagine you are no stranger to SO and know that a question like this will be downvoted for being opinion based with no clear answer.

Answer (score -1):

First you have to define on which hardware platform your POS system should run. This selection determines the languages.
E.g. you want to build POS on Android then you have Java and Kotlin available. Or you use HTML5 and JavaScript because you want to operate responsive design.
In any case, you first have to know which devices your application should run on.

Comment: I guess I should have stated (my apologies) it is going to be installed onto a linux based computer with off site data storage